# how to increase time by 15 mins using c#

Tags: c#, datetime

```
int inc = 15;
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Today;//new DateTime(2013,9,6,18,40,0,DateTimeKind.Local);//DateTime.Today.AddHours(10).AddMinutes(50);
DateTime endTime = DateTime.Today.AddHours(18).AddMinutes(35);//DateTime.Now;
List<DateTime> timeList = new List<DateTime>();
//while (startTime < DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(inc))
while (startTime < endTime.AddMinutes(inc))
{
    timeList.Add(startTime);
    startTime = startTime.AddMinutes(inc);
    Console.WriteLine(startTime);
}
```

the above one is not working.can you please providea solution.

real question:

> i need only time but date also coming thats why i seek help

Comment: what do you want to achieve by this? There is no question here.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'not working'? You need to be more specific, e.g. error, not as expected, wrong output, etc.

Comment: i want to show list of time which increase by 15 mins for a single day which starts from current time

Comment: wrong output,the program is wrong i hope so

Comment: @Sridhar works for me - I guess. It outputs dates increasing value by 15 mins

Comment: i need only time but date also coming thats why i seek help

Comment: @Sridhar change your writeline to Console.WriteLine(startTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));

Comment: So why is jquery a tag here? makes no sense. Also nowhere in this question did you mention that you just want the time, which is the only thing you actually want answered. I am very tempted to downvote this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to format your output to give you only time part. Change your write to:

```
Console.WriteLine(startTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
```

you can read more on formatting strings here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by this way. Here, Start time will be current time and end time will be the end of the day time, means if today is 19-Dec-2017 then end time will be 19-Dec-2017 11:59:59 PM

```
  int inc = 15;
  DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
  DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).Date.AddTicks(-1);
  List<DateTime> timeList = new List<DateTime>();

  Console.WriteLine("startTime:: " + startTime);
  Console.WriteLine("endTime:: " + endTime);

  while (startTime < endTime)
  {
    timeList.Add(startTime);
    Console.WriteLine(startTime.TimeOfDay);
    startTime = startTime.AddMinutes(inc);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I find for loop simpler for this. You can check below:

```
        int inc = 15;
        DateTime startTime = DateTime.Today;//new DateTime(2013,9,6,18,40,0,DateTimeKind.Local);//DateTime.Today.AddHours(10).AddMinutes(50);
        DateTime endTime = DateTime.Today.AddHours(18).AddMinutes(35);//DateTime.Now;
        List<DateTime> timeList = new List<DateTime>();
        //while (startTime < DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(inc))

        for (DateTime i = startTime; i < endTime; i = i.AddMinutes(inc))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i.ToString("HH:mm:sss"));
        }
```